# Total And GrandTotal CUBE different

Tags: mdx, etl, olap, cube

I Have CUBE table that support the pivot table like this

[image]

why the grand total diifrent with the TOTAL?
is there something wrong with MDX?

Comment: So what's the different between `total` and `grandtotal`?

Comment: Actually its like subtotal and total

Comment: so what's formula behind them?